# Can't see anything under row 119

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I created a dashboard in Excel with a bunch of hidden pivot tables I used as a reference. It's been touched by a couple hands, and at some point, I wasn't able to select anything below row 119. This is a particular problem because this is where all of the reference tables are located. Does anyone know how I can get access to the entire worksheet?

Comment: Are the rows hidden? In other words, can you see the row numbers off to the left-hand-side?

Comment: So I think they are hidden. But I think that I also hid ALL subsequent rows, so I can't there are no row headers for me to click "unhide".

Comment: I'm trying to post a picture but I'm getting internal server errors.

Comment: Try highlighting the rows before and after the hidden rows, right click, and select unhide.

Comment: It's basically all white after row 119. No headers. Nothing that I can select. If I unhide at row 119, nothing happens. If I hide row 119, it disappears as well. Which is why I think I hid all proceeding rows.

Comment: I wonder if you have windows frozen. Can you select `View --> Freeze Panes -->Unfreeze Panes`?

Comment: ^^ The frozen window panes is the thing that usually annoys me by causing this "problem"

Comment: Got ti! Thanks for your help. I think it might have been a matter of extremely fine motor movement with my mouse. I stumbled across the in between mark while playing around with it. Thanks again!

Comment: I actually did unfreeze panes before I did this. So maybe it unlocked it...

Answer (score 1):

Click and hold the row number 119 and drag it down a little bit no matter if you don't see any visible rows down, then right click on row number 119 and choose Unhide.

Comment: Got it! I'm not sure if this helped or not. But while playing around with it, I stumbled across a small sliver that gave my cursor the double lines that means I'm selecting in between rows. I pressed unhide and found row 100 thousand something! Thank you!

Comment: You can also F5, (type in) 119:100000, OK then right-click and unhide.